# css wont' style popover content or title

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, server, live

```
.popover-title{
    padding: 8px 14px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #337AB7 !important;
    text-align: center;
}.popover-content{
    padding: 9px 14px;
    color: #337AB7 !important;
```

This is live at draegerslikeus.com.  ( i know i need to scramble my email yet)

Local, I see the popovers (services section) styled with the blue font face.

On my phone I see it styled, but on chrome and IE (both updated) it's still white.

Answer (score -1):

You mistyped the property name.

`text-color: #337AB7 !important`

A simple right click + inspect element would have revealed the issue, if you didn't know about the inspector tools.

Comment: well, I searched the class, and used the "text" pane.   in DW cc, its rendering it as white, where as before it was blue, using color: :S.  i'll try it live

Comment: I can't help with Dreamweaver since I don't use it at all. That line is located on line 24 of `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: my style to .popover-content is being overridden with .service-item.